# heroku "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." following Hartl's RoR guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm following Michael Hartl's guide on learning Ruby on Rails and I just finished Chapter 5.

I get the localhost to load just fine and pages work and look as expected but when I try the final line to get heroku going "heroku open" I get the following screen (http://take.ms/4KuwQ).

I've tried checking other stackoverflow questions but still couldn't find the answer. The guide says to look at Heroku logs to debug but I can not find the solution.

Below is my entire Heroku log. I have also attached a screen grab (http://take.ms/MaJhz) of what I believe would be the issue but can not find the solution.

**Entire GEM file:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

**Entire Heroku log:**

```
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.780234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14
.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.781574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:13:14.782201+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:13:14.782201+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:13:14.783441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=damp-inlet-1921.herokuapp.com request_id=f19f1fc7-892c-4b1f-adaa-324bc982b675 fwd="12.172.95.252" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=350ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-04-16T23:13:15.127296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=damp-inlet-1921.herokuapp.com request_id=6b5c668d-189b-42d6-90b9-1bffb1d7f085 fwd="12.172.95.252" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-04-16T23:13:13.951347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-16T23:14:24.040669+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by edgarmatevosyan@gmail.com
2014-04-16T23:14:27.184585+00:00 heroku[run.2955]: Awaiting client
2014-04-16T23:14:27.219046+00:00 heroku[run.2955]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
2014-
04-16T23:14:27.274133+00:00 heroku[run.2955]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-16T23:14:30.722822+00:00 heroku[run.2955]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-16T23:14:30.708839+00:00 heroku[run.2955]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-16T23:14:37.126865+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by edgarmatevosyan@gmail.com
2014-04-16T23:14:41.972185+00:00 heroku[run.8896]: Awaiting client
2014-04-16T23:14:41.719744+00:00 heroku[run.8896]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-16T23:14:42.035485+00:00 heroku[run.8896]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-04-16T23:14:48.674142+00:00 heroku[run.8896]: Process exited with status 0
2014-04-16T23:14:48.685250+00:00 heroku[run.8896]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-16T23:23:59.044087+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 12.172.95.252 at 2014-04-16 23:23:59 +0000
2014-04-16T23:23:59.062462+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 12.172.95.252 at 2014-04-16 23:23:59 +0000
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
201
4-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289665+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.289857+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]: 
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.293486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-16T23:23:59.317925+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=damp-inlet-1921.herokuapp.com request_id=b7a6b34b-bab5-4603-b19e-5e00f6239f27 fwd="12.172.95.252" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=4147ms status=404 bytes=1616
```

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: Can we see `routes.rb`?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't `git push`ed everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screengrab log says no route matches a GET request on '/'. Are you sure you've set a root route? It would look like this: (the routes file is found in 'config/routes.rb')

```
root to: 'controller#method'
```

Where controller is the controller you wish to use 'users' or 'posts' etc..
and the method would most likely be an index method.

Take a quick look at routes.rb, and if you do have a line like I've mentioned above, just post up your routes.rb file for us to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've posted my routes.rb file

Comment: Yep. I see the line: Just add 'to:' after the word 'root' in that file.